# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'myclass'

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to understand how to build importable cython extension classes. As far as I understand, you must create a `.pxd` file like so:

`test.pxd`

```
cdef class myclass():
    cdef int a
    cdef int b
```

a `.pyx` file like so:

`test.pyx`

```
cdef class myclass():
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.a = 3
        self.b = 4
```

a setup file:

`setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("test.pyx")
)
```

And then build with 
`$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

But when I try to cimport

```
cimport test
```

I get this error:

```
----> 1 cdef class myclass():
      2     cdef int a
      3     cdef int b

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'myclass'
```

I'm sure it is very simple, but I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Something bizarre just occurred: When I deleted the \_\_init\_\_.py file, everything works...

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but there's a standard Python module called `test` which makes it a bad name for your own modules